# Setting Static IP for computers under a Switch

Tags: switch, ip

i have a fixed Line, to which The router is connected (DHCP Enabled) Dynamic IP. 
I have a Switch connected to the Router. (8 Port TP Link)

I have four machines connected to the switch and the count could go up soon. I need static IP addresses to be configured to some of the machines, which act as servers to others. So, having a static IP for these machines is necessary.

I tried configuring Static IP and disabling DHCP on swtich, but this configuration isn't working. I tried enabling DHCP on switch and router too. Even this doesn't work.

Any advice on how this could be set.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't have multiple DHCP servers enabled unless they're specially configured to coexist.

In your case, I suggest enabling it on the router, disabling everywhere else.  Then either: a) limiting the DHCP range (perhaps to 192.168.0.128 to .254) and configuring your statically-assigned equipment outside that range (perhaps gw=.1, server=.2 etc), or b) using reservations on the DHCP server so that it always gives ethernet address X a particular IP address.

Comment: Assigning static ip in router can be done. But router is expecting dhcp to be turned off for this. Maybe firm ware upgrade is needed or my router is too old to support.